# Windows Mobile 6.x and CDFS

Tags: windows-mobile, usb, windows-ce

Windows Mobile 6.x is based on Windows CE 5.x and it doesn't have CDFS driver included, even if the 5.x CE platform has support for it.

I have a scenario with an USB memory stick which contains also a CDFS partition, the PDA is running Windows Mobile 6.x and has OTG support (the host or client is selectable by the user). Is it feasible to move somehow the CE existing driver into Windows Mobile?

Any hint, direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Too many acronyms for me to follow you. What's CDFS? What's OTG?

Comment: @jp2code CDFS - Compact Disc File System, OTG - USB On-The-Go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is so proper to answer my own question, but maybe this answer it will be useful for others.

As I wrote the WinCE 5.x platform has CDFS support, while Windows Mobile 6.x doesn't. I just copied the WinCE 5.x driver - `udfs.dll` into the "Windows" directory of the Windows Mobile Device and added two registry settings:

```
; Default values for udfs. These can be overridden per profile.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\UDFS]
    "FriendlyName"="CDFS/UDFS FileSystem"
    "Dll"="udfs.dll"
    "Paging"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles\CDProfile]
    "Name"="IDE CDROM/DVD Drive"
    "Folder"="CDROM Drive"
    "DefaultFileSystem"="UDFS"
    "PartitionDriver"=""
```

I restarted the PDA and the CDFS support enabled. Mode details in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885283.aspx).